# How to check Thread has Completed and show a Toast

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm developing an android app, i have a separate class that extends `Thread` class, here i call a service and fetch data, now i need to know when this thread is completed and on completion its shows me a Toast.
Like
   "Successful"

Is there any method like `onPostExecute()` in `AsyncTask` Thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Display a toast is different that modify Views component because toast can be displayed from every thread while views need to be accessed only from the main thread.
So, if you need just to display a Thread just call `Toast.makeToast(...).show()` wherever you are.

Anyway, you can send messages from a backgrund thread to the main thread using the `Handler` class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading

Answer (score 1):

i hope you are using thread like this..

```
 .....
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    YourMetod();  //you want to execute first                              
    finishedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);//when first method is executed completly you need to call this
  }
 }).start();
 ....
```

create a handler in your class
like this

```
 private Handler finishedHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //create your toast here
     }
 };
```

try this hope help